# Getting Port Number at which NodeJS server is listening

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to retrieve the port number on which NodeJS is listening on. Currently I saving the port number value in app.js variable and trying to access it in index.js file. However, I am getting `undefined` value in index.js file. I am not sure why is this happening. How can I fix this?

**index.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = require('../app');
var router = express.Router();
var socket = require('socket.io');

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
  console.log("port: "+ app.portNumber);
  socket.listen(app.portNumber);
});


module.exports = router;
```

**app.js:**

var portNumber;
// rest of the controller code which calls the correct routes when a webpage is requested.

**www.js:**

/**
 * Get port from environment and store in Express.
 */

```
var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3000');
app.set('port', port);
app.portNumber = port;
```

Answer (score 1):

> This will export the variable port and will be available whenever you
>   import it var app = require('../app');

app.js:

```
var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3000');
app.set('port', port);
app.portNumber = port;

exports = module.exports = {
  portNumber : port
}
```

index.js:

```
var app = require('../app');
console.log("port: "+ app.portNumber);
```

Comment: Sorry for the previous mistake.. I directly used export without object there.. This example must work for you